# How can I have selenium ide run my custom javascript with jquery as it executes in firefox console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I have the below Javascript code with Jquery that runs fine in the console of firefox. How can I add this as a unit test in selenium ide and have it compare the output with the expected truth test output?

```
// Get text from account row and determine if text is Ascending or Descending
var tdArray = [];

$('.sorting_1').each(function(){
    $(this).find('strong').each(function(){
        tdArray.push(this.textContent);
    });
});

// ascending check
function isSorted(array){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
        return false;
    }
}
    return true;
}

isSorted(tdArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

verifyEval is a good place to get started.
http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.com/2013/06/selenium-ide-plug-in-example-for.html

Comment: I used verifyEval with no success, I tried wrapping the script with javascript{} or without I get the same error: 

[error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: $(...) is undefined.

Comment: Ahh I see. I'm having trouble getting your javascript to execute in the IDE context.

Answer (score 0):

In the application I test, there are numerous search results with multiple columns that can be sorted. Note that in my environment, once a column is sorted, there is a sort caret element that indicates the direction of the sort (Default for all columns is ascending on first click, descending on second click).

click | link=columnheader |
waitForElementPresent | css=th.sortasc |  (this is the sort caret element)

Then I grab the data from that column for the first two rows (or top row and bottom row of the results page).

storeText | //td/div/a | T1
storeTest | //tr[2]/td/div/a | T2

Then just compare.

storeEval | var isLess = false; isLess = eval(storedVars['T1'] <= storedVars['T2']); | isLess

verifyExpression | ${isLess} | true

For descending sorts, I use "isGreater"

Comment: What if the sort broke on row 500 for example. My script would catch that error, this method would not.

Comment: That is true, but are you going to really run a test to go through all 3 million rows of results (at least, that's what I'm dealing with).  In most cases, if the data is sorted properly on the first couple of pages, that's enough of a "pass" to pass the feature.  What you're referring to might be an edge case, but nothing to fail the feature.

Comment: The point is that it will catch the edge case because the current table I'm working with had issues where the sort broke halfway down, and if I could get selenium to just execute the script I wrote, I don't see how its anymore complex then your method while still catching the edge cases for what might be a few extra seconds of test run time.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a little trick you can do. I had an add on which exports HAR files, but I couldn't call it from Selenium IDE as it was not declared.

From Selenium IDE: **Command= "Go"** and **Target= "javascript:alert("hello")"**